# How to use CKEdior plugin Mention to allow white space for query?

Tags: ckeditor4.x, mention

I am using this plugin https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/mentions.html

However, it stops searching after typed whitespace. And the configuration seems doesn't have setting for it.

Please help out. 
Or is any alternative plugin for tagging user?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?